# Javascript on click event for child content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this on click event in my javascript

```
$('.nav_options_ele').on('click', function (e) {}
```

Which clicks when the user clicks on the `nav_options_ele` div

However, the on click doesn't work when the user clicks on some text inside the div as seen below

```
<li class="nav_options_ele" id="hot_topics">
    <span class="nav_options_text">Hot Topics</span>
</li>
```

How do i also make it run the code when the user clicks the text as well

Comment: Do you have any event handlers bound to the `span` in the `li`?

Comment: There should be a stopPropagation for the children. Could you search your code for it...

Comment: no i don't have any bound to the span

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/TLuZx/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok basically I got it working by putting the same Id in the li in the span as well.

Answer (score 0):

try it this way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav_options_ele').on('click', function (e) {
        alert('clicked');
    });

});
```

wait for the content to load

here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/7WcaV/

Answer (score 0):

Your example works fine for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/swy3Q/

```
$('.nav_options_ele').on('click', function (e) {
    alert('clicked');
});

<li class="nav_options_ele" id="hot_topics">
   <span class="nav_options_text">Hot Topics</span>
</li>
```

When you use events on HTML, the events will be attached to all of the nested HTML as well.  Maybe you're missing the ); at the end of your event declaration?

Answer (score -1):

Use
    $("[class^=nav_option]").on('click', function(){});

Comment: Why are you suggesting this? There is nothing wrong with the OP's code.